# Internal Server Error on Send Test Mail

Tags: emails, error-handling, global-configuration, joomla-mail

Im using Joomla 4.1.0
When i try to send a test mail, from Global Configuration - Server - Mail, i get the following error message.
"An error has occurred while fetching the JSON data: HTTP 500 status code. Internal Server Error"
Mailer is SMTP
using SMTP port 587, and security SSL/TLS

Comment: I'm not sure that we have enough diagnostic detail to confidently provide a solution for you.  If you can offer more details/clues, please [edit] your question.  Also, please take our [tour] while you wait for turther feedback/support.

Comment: If you turn on Debug and Error reporting to Maximum or Development in the Global settings you should get more detailed information about where the problem is occurring.